# SQL: conditional queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update all entries in a table with value 23 in column called test to the value 24. My table is called members. What would the SQL query look like?

Comment: what did you try ? search for update query

Comment: I tried "UPDATE members SET test=24 WHERE test=23" and it didn't work. Using single quotes around the numbers seemed to work!

Comment: well may be the datatype of test is varchar

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE members SET test = '24' WHERE test = '23'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE members set test=24 where test=23?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it, if test is int type othervise use "24" and "23"

```
update member
set test=24
where test=23
```

Answer (score 0):

if Test is the varchar datatype.

```
update members set test='24' where test='23'
```

if Test is int data type

```
update members set test=24 where test=23
```

It will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this sql**

```
 UPDATE members SET test = '24' WHERE test = '23'
```

**It was very simple query,I think you should learn basic of sql language. from this w3school link**

[SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/)